# $\lim\limits_{t\to \infty} \frac{t^n}{e^t}$

Tags: limits

I was solving a question and stuck on a step where I'd to evaluate the limit: $\lim\limits_{t\to \infty} \dfrac{t^n}{e^t}$.

So my initial thought was to apply L'Hôpital's rule since it is of the form $\dfrac{\infty}{\infty}$.

Applying L'Hôpital's rule makes it more difficult to be evaluated.

Is there any easy method to solve it?

Comment: Do induction on $n$. Use L'H for the indutive step.

Comment: @Justauser How to do induction on n? I'm not aware about induction.

Comment: Please do not make subject lines made up entirely of mathjax. It messes up some navigation shortcuts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that for all non-negative integers $n$ and any $t>0$ we have
$$
e^t=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!}>\frac {t^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}
.$$
Hence
$$
\frac{t^n}{e^t}<\frac{(n+1)!}{t}
.$$
Now let $t\rightarrow\infty$ .

Answer (score 4):

Applying l'Hôpital's rule shows that
$$\lim\limits_{t\to \infty} \frac{t^n}{e^t}=\lim\limits_{t\to \infty} \frac{nt^{n-1}}{e^t}.$$
Repeating $n$ times thus shows that
$$\lim\limits_{t\to \infty} \frac{t^n}{e^t}=\lim\limits_{t\to \infty} \frac{n!}{e^t}=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

You may know that
$$
\frac{e^t}{t} \underset{t \rightarrow + \infty}{\longrightarrow} + \infty
$$
so forall $a > 0$, using that $\lim_{x \infty}x^a = + \infty$ you get
$$
\left(\frac{e^t}{t}\right)^a = \frac{e^{at}}{t^a} \underset{t \rightarrow + \infty}{\longrightarrow} + \infty.
$$
Then use $\lim_{x \infty} x/a = + \infty$ to get
$$
\frac{e^t}{(t/a)^a} = a^{-a} \frac{e^t}{t^a}\underset{t \rightarrow + \infty}{\longrightarrow} +\infty
$$
and then
$$
\frac{e^t}{t^a}\underset{t \rightarrow + \infty}{\longrightarrow} +\infty.
$$